# What's the correct selector to use for this jQuery slideUp code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle, slideup

I am using Foundation to create a page where I will have multiple collapsed buttons. When you click on the button, the hidden content within it will slide down and if there are any expanded buttons they will slide up.

I have this partially working, but because I have the buttons in pairs of two I can't figure out the right selector to get the expanded divs to close regardless of where they're positioned.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="box">
        Initial Content
        <div class="hidden">
            This is hidden content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        Initial Content
        <div class="hidden">
            This is hidden content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="box">
        Initial Content
        <div class="hidden">
            This is hidden content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        Initial Content
        <div class="hidden">
            This is hidden content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    height:auto;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:200px;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
.hidden {
    height:200px;
    display:none;
}
    .hidden.open {
        display:block;
    }
```

And Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.hidden').slideToggle();
        $(this).siblings().find('.hidden').slideUp();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6C42Q/26/) to demonstrate what I have so far.

Comment: Its working perfect. What exactly do you need? Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6C42Q/27/. Removed line 2 `$(this).siblings().find('.hidden').slideUp();` Just `find()` is enough

Comment: Works for me too. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @ShaunakD - Click the third box, then the second. See how the third box stays open because it's in a different group of divs?

Comment: It's only partially working. Because the buttons are separated into 2 different parent divs, you can have multiple buttons toggled open. However @j08691 response below worked great, thanks everyone!

Comment: Ohh, it was right there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add one line to take care of it:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.hidden').slideUp();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6C42Q/29/)**